# How to bring a window to foreground using window caption(Excel VBA)?

Tags: html, vba, excel

Am working on Automating a Web application using Excel. Everything was going fine, till the moment i got struck with a window being in the background.

A window with caption "Role manager" is open. How can i bring the window to foreground?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `AppActivate "Role manager"`brings the window to the front and sets focus to it

Comment: If `AppActivate()` doesn't do the trick then you'll have to look at using WinAPI

Comment: @gizmeier, excellent! upvoting where possible.

Comment: @gizlmeier AppActivate is working fine. Thank you!!
How can i mark this Question as answered??

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks for your suggestion.